# Parameter 0 of constructor in 'ItemController' required a bean of type '.ItemRepository' that could not be found. (Spring Data Cloud Firestore)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, google-cloud-firestore, spring-cloud

I'm new to Spring and after creating a first simple project using the "standard" APIs, I'm trying to integrate everything with Google Firestore using the Spring Cloud GCPs, in particular those related to Firestore (Spring Data Cloud Firestore). But I keep running into this error and I can't figure it out:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 0 of constructor in 'com.example.spring_backend.ItemController' required a bean of type 'com.example.spring_backend.ItemRepository' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.example.spring_backend.ItemRepository' in your configuration.
```

My project structure is this:

[image]

I've put in **application.properties** the **project name** and the path to the **key** of my GC service.

Here is the code of various files:

**Item.Java:**

```java
@Document(collectionName = "items")
public class Item {

    @DocumentId
    private String name;
    
    private ArrayList<String> labels;
    private Boolean classified;
    private String base64;

    // Constructors
    public Item() {
    }

    public Item(String name, String base64) {
        this.name = name;
        this.labels = null;
        this.classified = false;
        this.base64 = base64;
    }

    public Item(String name, ArrayList<String> labels, String base64) {
        this.name = name;
        this.labels = labels;
        this.classified = false;
        this.base64 = base64;
    }

    public Item(String name, Boolean classified, ArrayList<String> labels, String base64) {
        this.name = name;
        this.labels = labels;
        this.classified = classified;
        this.base64 = base64;
    }

    public Item(String name, boolean classified, ArrayList<String> labels) {
        this.name = name;
        this.labels = labels;
        this.classified = classified;
        this.base64 = null;
    }

    // Getters and Setters
}
```

**ItemController.java:**

```java
@CrossOrigin
@RestController
public class ItemController {

    private final ItemRepository itemRepository;

    ItemController(ItemRepository repository) {
        this.itemRepository = repository;
    }

    @GetMapping("/items")
    public Flux<Item> all() {
        System.out.print("ciao");

        return itemRepository.findAll();
    }

    @PostMapping("/save")
    public Mono<Item> newEmployee(@RequestBody Item item) {

        System.out.print("ciao");

        item.setClassified(false);
        item.setLabels(new ArrayList<String>());

        // ! Da togliere
        item.setBase64(null);

        return itemRepository.save(item);
    }
}
```

**ItemRepository.java:**

```java
public interface ItemRepository extends FirestoreReactiveRepository<Item>{
}
```

**SpringBackendApplication.java:**

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringBackendApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringBackendApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

**pom.xml**:

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2</version>
    </parent>

    <name>spring_backend</name>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring_backend</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>3.4.0</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-data-firestore</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

**Full stack trace**:

```bash
2023-01-23T15:20:20.257+01:00  INFO 10996 --- [           main] c.e.s.SpringBackendApplication           : Starting SpringBackendApplication using Java 17.0.5 with PID 10996 (/home/beppetemp/Tirocinio_NTTData/components/backend/target/classes started by beppetemp in /home/beppetemp/Tirocinio_NTTData)
2023-01-23T15:20:20.263+01:00  INFO 10996 --- [           main] c.e.s.SpringBackendApplication           : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2023-01-23T15:20:21.510+01:00  INFO 10996 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2023-01-23T15:20:21.522+01:00  INFO 10996 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2023-01-23T15:20:21.522+01:00  INFO 10996 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine    : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.1.5]
2023-01-23T15:20:21.699+01:00  INFO 10996 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2023-01-23T15:20:21.703+01:00  INFO 10996 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1322 ms
2023-01-23T15:20:21.842+01:00  WARN 10996 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'itemController' defined in file [/home/beppetemp/Tirocinio_NTTData/components/backend/target/classes/com/example/spring_backend/ItemController.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: No qualifying bean of type 'com.example.spring_backend.ItemRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
2023-01-23T15:20:21.848+01:00  INFO 10996 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2023-01-23T15:20:21.884+01:00  INFO 10996 --- [           main] .s.b.a.l.ConditionEvaluationReportLogger : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2023-01-23T15:20:21.969+01:00 ERROR 10996 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 0 of constructor in com.example.spring_backend.ItemController required a bean of type 'com.example.spring_backend.ItemRepository' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.example.spring_backend.ItemRepository' in your configuration.
```

Someone can help me ?

Comment: What are your dependencies, configuration? The `@Repository` on the interface doesn't do anything (only takes up space), the `@Autowired` on the `final` field in your controller also only takes up spaces as the dependency is injected through the constructor. Please find the full stacktrace and post that and not the analyzed failure message. The fact that it isn't there probably means you are missing a dependency and/or configuration.

Comment: I've added the information required. Thanks for the answer

Comment: have you tried putting `ItemRepository.java` to a new package inside your package, like `spring_backend/repository/ItemRepository.java`? I guess spring boot scans packages inside `spring_backend`, but there are none. I agree with @M.Deinum that Autowired only takes up space, but Repository should be enough to create a bean.

Comment: Tried now but nothing, same error

Comment: No `@Repository` doesn't create a bean because it is an interface, Spring Data detects repositories in a different way. It will scan the current and all child packages, moving it to a sub-package won't solve a thing. If that was the case it wouldn't detect the controller as well (which it does).

Comment: @M.Deinum I've update the code and the post, according yuor first comment but the problem is the same.

Comment: I nowhere stated that that would solve your problem, but those are things to improve your code as they don't add anything but clutter. I wanted your configuration/dependencies (and the latter are your problem as you can see in my answer).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using Spring Boot but your `spring-cloud-gcp-dependencies` is compatible with Spring Boot 2.6/2.7 and not Spring Boot 3. Hence it doesn't work.

You need to either:

1. Downgrade to Spring Boot 2.7.x
2. Use the `4.0.0-SNAPSHOT` versions of the `spring-cloud-gcp-dependencies` dependencies which are compatible with Spring Boot 3.x.

See also [the version compatibility matrix](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/spring-cloud-gcp#compatibility-with-spring-project-versions).

For option 2 you will need to add the repository, as mentioned [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/spring-cloud-gcp#snapshots-repository) to your Maven file.

Comment: I get this error on the **dependecyManager** block in **pom.xml**: `Project build error: Non-resolvable import POM: Could not find artifact com.google.cloud:spring-cloud-gcp-dependencies:pom:4.0.0-SNAPSHOTJava(0)`

Comment: It is a SNAPSHOT and that probably isn't available from Maven central, you need to figure out which repository holds it and add it to your pom. See https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/spring-cloud-gcp#snapshots-repository

Comment: ah ok, I'll try to find how to do it then, because I'm not very familiar with Maven.

Comment: Nothing to do: `Project build error: Non-resolvable import POM: com.google.cloud:spring-cloud-gcp-dependencies:pom:4.0.0-SNAPSHOT was not found in https://google.oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots during a previous attempt. This failure was cached in the local repository and resolution is not reattempted until the update interval of snapshots-repo has elapsed or updates are forcedJava(0)`

Comment: I've upload the update pom.xml

Comment: Well the error tells you that they haven't uploaded a version 4.0.0 snapshot. If you browse the URL you will also see it isn't available. Regardless one of the options in the answer is your solution but as there is no snapshot released yet your only option (for now) is to downgrade Spring Boot.

Comment: that solve the problem, adding latest version of spring-cloud-gcp .

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to **M. Deinum's** answer I understood that it was a dependency problem, so I created a new project with [Spring Initializer](https://start.spring.io/) adding in **Spring GCP** dependencies.

The resulting pom.xml is:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.8</version>
        <relativePath/>
        <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <name>spring_backend</name>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring_backend</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <spring-cloud-gcp.version>3.4.2</spring-cloud-gcp.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2021.0.5</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud-gcp.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-data-firestore</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```